# Similar validation functions don't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, tkinter, tkinter-entry

First of all, sorry for not using OOP, I just decided to avoid complexity for such a small program.
So here's my program (basically, it's an Entry widget that allows a text that only consists of integers whose maximum length is 5):

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Entry Validation")
root.geometry("300x100")

def validation_function(text):
    if len(text) <= 5:
        try:
            text = int(text)
            return True
        except:
            return False
    else:
        return False

vcmd = root.register(validation_function)
entry = Entry(root, validate='key', validatecommand=(vcmd, "%P"))
entry.pack()
```

It works normal. But when I make a little change in the body of the validation function, it doesn't work:

```
def validation_function(text):
    try:
        text = int(text)
        if len(text) <= 5:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False
```

I feel the problem is here:

```
except:
    return False
```

Probably the max length part doesn't go well with try-except... However:

```
def validation_function(text):
    try:
        if len(text) <= 5:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except:
        return False
```

works correctly. But there is only the max length part, I also want it to allow only integers. I've done it in the first example, but my question is: why doesn't it work when I change the places of the max length part with the only integers part?

Comment: Please don't downvote my questions without explaining the reason! It limits my privileges. I'm just new here, guys, come on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text` is an `int` ... you cannot call `len(int)` ... it will raise an exception

try this

```
def validation_function(text):
    try:
        int(text)
    except:
        return False
    if len(text) <= 5:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: That's right! It raises a TypeError normally, and in this case an exception. I had to give attention to that... Thanks!

Comment: Excuse me, one more question about it: why am I having trouble when I try to delete the entry text? I even use a clear function bound to the entry widget, so when I click the entry area, it must get cleared; I also added a clear button to vanish the entry text after clicking the button, but neither of them works. Is there any way to fix it? I tried many ways, but none of them worked out.

Comment: Solved using:
if not text:
     None
     return True